# Restart kube-apiserver when provisioned with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

When provisioning a kubernetes cluster with `kubeadmin init` it creates a cluster which keeps the `kube-apiserver`, `etcd`, `kube-controller-manager` and `kube-scheduler` processes within docker containers.

Whenever some configuration (e.g. access tokens) for the `kube-apiserver` is changed, I've to restart the related server. While I could usually run `systemctl restart kube-apiserver.service` on other installations, I've kill the docker container on that installation or restart the system to restart it.

So is there a better way to restart the `kube-apiserver`?

Comment: Hi @pagid, I had a very similar problem where I want to restart kube-scheduler with a new configuration after creating a cluster with `kubeadm`. Have you figured out the way to restart these control component. It would be great if you could share your experience with me . Thanks

Comment: My question is linked here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949983/how-to-restart-the-kubernetes-kube-scheduler-of-a-k8s-cluster-built-by-kubeadm

Answer (score 17):

You can delete the kube-apiserver Pod. It's a [static Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/static-pods/) (in case of a kubeadm installation) and will be recreated immediately.

If I recall correctly the manifest directory for that installation is /etc/kubernetes/manifest, but I will check later and edit this answer. Just doing a touch on the kube-apiserver.json will also recreate the Pod.

Comment: The exact path is: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` but you won't be able to re-create it with `kubectl create ..` because.. the API server is down. I had this problem and after I ran `systemctl restart kubelet` it fixed the problem. This was also mention by the link for static pod @Janos Lenart mentioned.

Comment: deleting the pod does not restart the container

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a command for that:

```
docker restart <containername/ID>
```

Some configuration changes will be applied by **reloading** the services. Like common directives in nginx.conf. If your service supports reload you can try the following:

```
docker kill -s HUP <nginx container>
```

This will reload nginx service.

Restarting container's main process will make the container stop.

> I've kill the docker container on that installation or restart the
>   system to restart it.

Please dont restart the whole server for this.

Comment: Hi, not sure if you read my question properly. I know that this could be done with docker kill, but was asking whether there is some *better* way to do it. Responding with the solution I already know doesn't help.

Comment: And Im leaving the answer here so I can help others anyway.

Comment: It doesn't help to rewrite a solution for a common problem under a question about an uncommon problem. Just makes it hard to the rest of us to find what we're looking for

Answer (score 3):

docker ps -af 'name=k8s_POD_(kube-apiserver|kube-controller-manager|kube-scheduler|etcd)-*' -q | /usr/bin/xargs /bin/docker rm -f

Answer (score 0):

Temporary renaming files under /etc/kubernetes/manifests on master nodes causes pods recreation.

Another way is to restart the container running under pod. With containerd you need to remove the task first (which is docker equivalent of stopping the container), then remove the container:

```
# find id of your container
ctr -n k8s.io container ls
# get its pid
ctr -n k8s.io container info <container-id> | grep proc | grep path
# find task with pid
ctr -n k8s.io task ls | grep <pid>
# kill it
ctr -n k8s.io task kill <task-id>
# now you can remove the container too
ctr -n k8s.io container rm <container-id>
```