# How to restart the kubernetes kube-scheduler of a k8s cluster built by kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a kubernetes cluster by `kubeadm` following [this official tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/). Each of the control panel components (apiserver,control manager, kube-scheduler) is a running pod. I learned that kube-scheduler will be using some default scheduling policies ([defined here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/algorithmprovider/defaults/defaults.go)) when it is created by `kubeadm`. These default policies are a subset of all available policies ([listed here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/#scoring))

How can I restart the kube-scheduler pod with a new configuration(different policy list)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The kube-scheduler is a static pod managed by kubelet on the master node. So updating the kube-scheduler manifest file (`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`) will trigger the kube-scheduler to restart.